# Andropid SDK 20 - Can't open more than one avd

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have just updated to Android SDK Tools 20 and SDK Platform-Tools 12.

Now I find that, for some reason, I can't open more than one AVD at the same time.

Anyone else found this problem?

Comment: You are not the first to report this. Personally, I am having no problem running multiple AVDs.

Comment: Can you run an additional one from the command line?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I can't start a 2nd one from the command line in Windows or from Eclipse. If I start avd type 1 (OK), then try to start avd type 2 (fails), then kill type 1 avd and try to start avd type 3, then the 'queued up and failed' type 2 avd starts instead!

Comment: It also seems to be opening the wrong one sometimes. Kinda "remembers" the previous one and reopens that one.